Polarization tensor of graviton in $d$ dimensions
Take the following tensor, that is the sum over the two polarizations of a gravitational wave in 3 spatial dimensions:
$$E_{ijkl}(\vec{k})\equiv\sum_{\lambda = +,\times} \epsilon^\lambda_{ij}(\vec{k})\epsilon^\lambda_{kl}(\vec{k}).$$
where the two polarization tensors are defined as:
$$\epsilon^+_{ij}(\vec{k)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[e_i(\vec{k})e_j(\vec{k})-\bar{e}_i(\vec{k})\bar{e}_j(\vec{k})\right]$$
and
$$\epsilon^\times_{ij}(\vec{k)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[e_i(\vec{k})\bar{e}_j(\vec{k})+\bar{e}_i(\vec{k})e_j(\vec{k})\right]$$
where $\left(\hat{e}(\vec{k}),\hat{\bar{e}}(\vec{k}),\hat{k}\right)$ is an orthonormal basis of the 3-dimensional space in which $\hat{k}$ is the versor that indicates the direction of propagation of the gravitational wave.
My question is how to generalize this to $d$ spatial dimensions?
I found a formula that I am not sure it is correct. If it is, I would like to have a proof. The formula is:
$$E_{ijkl}(\vec{k}) = \frac{1}{2}\left(P_{ik}(\vec{k})P_{jl}(\vec{k})+P_{il}(\vec{k})P_{jk}(\vec{k})\right)-\frac{1}{d-1}P_{ij}(\vec{k})P_{kl}(\vec{k}),$$
where we have defined the following projector:
$$P_{ij}(\vec{k}) \equiv \delta_{ij}-\frac{k_i k_j}{k^2}.$$

Your second formula simply extracts the TT part of a tensor. It isn't directly related to the first part of your question which is about the number of GW polarizations in higher dimensions.

I already know that in d spatial dimensions the number of polarizations is $\frac{(d+1)(d-2)}{2}$. This is known in literature.
I need a close formula to do the integral in an internal momentum $\vec{p}$ variable in spherical coordinates. The tensor $E_{ijkl}(\vec{k})$ must be contracted with $p_i p_j p_k p_l$.
